# Multi-level list error

Tags: lists, enumerate

I have created a list that has a lot of levels, and have used resources from both TeX SE and ShareLaTeX to do so, but when I try to compile it, I get the error "Missing number, treated as zero" at numerous points within the code, and I cannot figure out why, as comparing the resources with my code suggests that it should work.

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlistdepth{6}
\newlist{myEnumerate}{enumerate}{7}
\setlist[myEnumerate, 1]{label=(\arabic)}
\setlist[myEnumerate, 2]{label=(\arabic)}
\setlist[myEnumerate, 3]{label=(\arabic)}
\setlist[myEnumerate, 4]{label=(\arabic)}
\setlist[myEnumerate, 5]{label=(\arabic)}
\setlist[myEnumerate, 6]{label=(\arabic)}
\setlist[myEnumerate, 7]{label=(\arabic)}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Here is an algorithm for $\overline{PATH}$. Let $m$ be the number of nodes in $G$. 

$M= \text{``On input } \langle G,s,t \rangle$
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item Let $c_0=1$
\item For $i=0$ to $m-1$:
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item Let $c_{i+1}=1$
\item For each node $v \neq s$ in $G$:
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item Let $d=0$
\item For each node $u$ in $G$:
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item Non-deterministically either perform or skip these steps:
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item Non-deterministically follow a path of length at most $i$ from $s$ and \textit{reject} if it doesn't end at $u$
\item Increment $d$
\item If $(u,v)$ is an edge of $G$, increment $c_{i+1}$ and go to Stage 5 with the next $v$
\item If $d \neq c_i$, then \textit{reject}
\item Let $d=0$
\item For each node $u$ in $G$:
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item Non-deterministically either perform or skip these steps:
\begin{myEnumerate}
\item Non-deterministically follow a path of length at most $m$ from $s$ and \textit{reject} if it doesn't end at $u$
\item If $u=t$ then \textit{reject}
\item Increment $d$
\item If $d \neq c_m$, then \textit{reject}
\item Otherwise, \textit{accept}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{myEnumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The final document that I am aiming for is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Use `\arabic*`, not `\arabic`. And if all levels are the same, why not just `\setlist[myEnumerate]{label=(\arabic*)}`?

Comment: Is it possible to have the numbers increment by one for each list item, even if it is in another list?

Comment: Somehow I feel that `enumerate` is not quite the right tool here. What exactly did you have in mind? (BTW: Do you mean `$\overline{PATH}$` or `$\overline{\mathit{PATH}}$`?)

Comment: I added an image of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a single enumerate and play with the indentation.  This solution uses `\parbox`es, so you cannot have an `\item` (or `\ibox`) split over a page boundary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\IndentLevel}
\setlength{\IndentLevel}{0pt}
\newenvironment{myindent}{\advance\IndentLevel by 1em}{}
\newcommand{\ibox}[1]{\item\hspace{\IndentLevel}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\IndentLevel}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\ibox{Let $c_0=1$}
\ibox{For $i=0$ to $m-1$:}
\begin{myindent}
\ibox{Let $c_{i+1}=1$}
\ibox{For each node $v \neq s$ in $G$:}
\begin{myindent}
\ibox{Let $d=0$}
\ibox{For each node $u$ in $G$:}
\begin{myindent}
\ibox{Non-deterministically either perform or skip these steps:}
\begin{myindent}
\ibox{Non-deterministically follow a path of length at most $i$ from $s$ and \textit{reject} if it doesn't end at $u$}
\ibox{Increment $d$}
\ibox{If $(u,v)$ is an edge of $G$, increment $c_{i+1}$ and go to Stage 5 with the next $v$}
\ibox{If $d \neq c_i$, then \textit{reject}}
\ibox{Let $d=0$}
\ibox{For each node $u$ in $G$:}
\begin{myindent}
\ibox{Non-deterministically either perform or skip these steps:}
\begin{myindent}
\ibox{Non-deterministically follow a path of length at most $m$ from $s$ and \textit{reject} if it doesn't end at $u$}
\ibox{If $u=t$ then \textit{reject}}
\ibox{Increment $d$}
\ibox{If $d \neq c_m$, then \textit{reject}}
\ibox{Otherwise, \textit{accept}}
\end{myindent}
\end{myindent}
\end{myindent}
\end{myindent}
\end{myindent}
\end{myindent}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I start to move out again when I get to step 11 onwards?

Comment: You step out every time you end the myindent environment.   The changes are local, not global.

Comment: Thank you! How can I do the information on the right?

Comment: To do both left and right at the same time, use `\hfill` between.  (Left, center and right is more complicated, involving \rlap and \llap.)